# Refactoring a Subclause in an Oracle Trigger with 'New' and 'Old' Value Dependencies

Tags: oracle

Consider the following Oracle trigger, which does not work because there is a sub-clause in each if statement

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER track_rm_area_t
BEFORE UPDATE OR INSERT ON RM
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN

    IF(:NEW.area IS NOT NULL) THEN
        INSERT INTO rm_area(bl_id, fl_id, rm_id, rm_cat, rm_type, area, date_effective, usable_flag)
        VALUES(:NEW.bl_id, :NEW.fl_id, :NEW.rm_id, :NEW.rm_cat, :NEW.rm_type, :NEW.area, SYSDATE, 
            CASE WHEN :NEW.rm_cat IN (SELECT rm_cat FROM rmcat WHERE supercat = 'USBL') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END);
    ELSIF(:NEW.rm_cat IS NOT NULL AND :OLD.rm_cat IS NOT NULL AND (:NEW.rm_cat <> :OLD.rm_cat)) THEN
        IF(
            :NEW.rm_cat IN (SELECT rm_cat FROM rmcat WHERE supercat = 'USBL') 
            AND :OLD.rm_cat NOT IN (SELECT rm_cat FROM rmcat WHERE supercat = 'USBL')
        ) THEN
        INSERT INTO rm_area(bl_id, fl_id, rm_id, rm_cat, rm_type, area, date_effective, usable_flag)
        VALUES(:NEW.bl_id, :NEW.fl_id, :NEW.rm_id, :NEW.rm_cat, :NEW.rm_type, :NEW.area, SYSDATE, 1);
        ELSIF 
        (
            :NEW.rm_cat NOT IN (SELECT rm_cat FROM rmcat WHERE supercat = 'USBL') 
            AND :OLD.rm_cat IN (SELECT rm_cat FROM rmcat WHERE supercat = 'USBL')
        ) THEN
        INSERT INTO rm_area(bl_id, fl_id, rm_id, rm_cat, rm_type, area, date_effective, usable_flag)
        VALUES(:NEW.bl_id, :NEW.fl_id, :NEW.rm_id, :NEW.rm_cat, :NEW.rm_type, :NEW.area, SYSDATE, 0);
        END IF;
    END IF;
END;
/
COMMIT;
```

At a high level, what I am trying to accomplish is this:

- Anytime time rm.area gets updated, insert a record into rm_area. If the room is usable, `rm_area.usable_flag` should be 1, and 0 if it is not. A room is defined as usable if `rm.rm_cat IN (SELECT rm_cat FROM rmcat WHERE rmcat.supercat = 'USBL')`
- If rm.rm_cat for an existing record gets updated such that the room is no longer usable or vice versa, insert a new record into rm_area with the modified flag and its existing area value.

I am aware that I need a variable and loop to run through all the values in the sub-query, but am not sure how to best factor this. When I tried the following:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER track_rm_area_t
BEFORE UPDATE OR INSERT ON RM
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE 
    usable_rm_cat VARCHAR(12 BYTE);
BEGIN
    FOR r IN (SELECT rm_cat INTO usable_rm_cat FROM rmcat WHERE supercat = 'USBL')
    LOOP
    usable_rm_cat := r.rm_cat;
    IF
    (
        :NEW.area IS NOT NULL OR 
        (
            :NEW.rm_cat IS NOT NULL AND :OLD.rm_cat IS NOT NULL AND (:NEW.rm_cat <> :OLD.rm_cat) AND
                (
                    (:OLD.rm_cat IN (usable_rm_cat) 
                    AND :NEW.rm_cat NOT IN (usable_rm_cat))

                    OR (:OLD.rm_cat NOT IN (usable_rm_cat)
                    AND :NEW.rm_cat IN (usable_rm_cat))
                )
        )
    ) THEN
        INSERT INTO rm_area(bl_id, fl_id, rm_id, rm_cat, rm_type, area, date_effective, usable_flag)
        VALUES(:NEW.bl_id, :NEW.fl_id, :NEW.rm_id, :NEW.rm_cat, :NEW.rm_type, :NEW.area, SYSDATE, 
            CASE WHEN :NEW.rm_cat IN (usable_rm_cat) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END);
            EXIT;
    END IF;
    END LOOP;
END;
/
COMMIT;
```

The `CASE` in the insert statement always yielded `0`.

To fix this, I thought about starting with the loop, then checking if `:NEW.rm_cat = r.rm_cat`, but that leaves me stuck as to how to best check the value of `:OLD.rm_cat` and handle the case where all updates to rm.area need to be tracked (this takes precedence over any value of rm_cat).

How can I create the trigger such that all values of rm.area are tracked and inserted in this new table, as well as the specific values of rm.rm_cat?

Answer (score 1):

I think you overcomplicated things, especially you don't need any loops here. Select values at first into variables and use them when inserting:

```
create or replace trigger track_rm_area_t
before update or insert on rm for each row
    v_old_usable int;
    v_new_usable int;
begin

    select nvl(max(case rm_cat when :old.rm_cat then 1 end), 0),
           nvl(max(case rm_cat when :new.rm_cat then 1 end), 0)
        into v_old_usable, v_new_usable 
        from rmcat
        where rm_cat in (:old.rm_cat, :new.rm_cat) and supercat = 'USBL';

    if :new.area is not null then

        insert into rm_area(bl_id, fl_id, rm_id, rm_cat, rm_type, area, 
            date_effective, usable_flag)
        values(:new.bl_id, :new.fl_id, :new.rm_id, :new.rm_cat, :new.rm_type, :new.area, 
            sysdate, v_new_usable);

    elsif :new.rm_cat is not null and :old.rm_cat is not null and :new.rm_cat <> :old.rm_cat 
        and v_old_usable <> v_new_usable then

        insert into rm_area(bl_id, fl_id, rm_id, rm_cat, rm_type, area, 
            date_effective, usable_flag)
        values(:new.bl_id, :new.fl_id, :new.rm_id, :new.rm_cat, :new.rm_type, :new.area, 
            sysdate, v_new_usable);

    end if;
end;
```

I have not your tables, so not tested. Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 0):

Triggers should always be very light weight. While it is done all the time, many consider it bad form to maintain ancillary tables with triggers. I have done this, and regretted it. I hope you never have to do a bulk load with a trigger like this. That said, do your count outside of the insert. Here is the first part of your SQL:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER track_rm_area_t
    BEFORE UPDATE OR INSERT
    ON rm
    FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
    l_cnt   INTEGER;
BEGIN
    IF (:new.area IS NOT NULL)
    THEN
        SELECT COUNT( * )     c
          INTO l_cnt
          FROM rmcat
         WHERE supercat = 'USBL' AND rm_cat = :new.rm_cat AND ROWNUM = 1;

        INSERT INTO rm_area( bl_id
                           , fl_id
                           , rm_id
                           , rm_cat
                           , rm_type
                           , area
                           , date_effective
                           , usable_flag )
             VALUES ( :new.bl_id
                    , :new.fl_id
                    , :new.rm_id
                    , :new.rm_cat
                    , :new.rm_type
                    , :new.area
                    , SYSDATE
                    , l_cnt );
. . .
```

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but wouldn't this track all category changes? I don't want to insert a record if the category changes and the room remains usable (or unusable). Also, why did you add the 'ROWNUM = 1' clause?

Comment: @ach00 `ROWNUM=1` leaves us with two possible values for usable_flag, 1 or 0. It also causes fetching to stop once a match is found.

I am not certain what you mean by "but wouldn't this track all category changes?"  The count predicate has `rm_cat = :new.rm_cat`, so it is restricted to the new value for rm_cat.